# Json data to MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I am new to the Json and PHP.  This is sample but I am trying to put the Json data into the MySQL using PHP  with this code I was able to input the Json data to the MySQL except the Json data ["@context": "dfg2"] can not put this data into the MySQL rest of the data like ["empid": "M01AH"], ["name":"Ricky Jones"] were able to put these value in the mySQL using PHP

Question is how can I put ["@context": "dfg2"] data into the MYSQL using PHP?
I know the using @ in the PHP script is not that good..

```
$json_obj = '{
      "empid": "M01AH",
      "personal": {
           "name":"Ricky Jones",
           "gender": "Male"
      },
      "profile": {
           "designation": "VP",
           "department": "Marketing",
              "@context": "dfg2"
      }
 }';
//If I take out @ in the [ "@context": "dfg2"] I can put the data in to the MYSQL


//convert to stdclass object
$emp_data = json_decode($json_obj);





//store the element values into variables
$id = $emp_data->empid;
$name = $emp_data->personal->name;
$gender = $emp_data->personal->gender;
$designation = $emp_data->profile->designation;
$department = $emp_data->profile->department;
$e = $emp_data->profile->@context;      //If I take out @ I can put the data in to the MYSQL How can I leave @ to make the data into the MYSQL




//insert values into mysql database　　
$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_employee (`empid`, `empname`, `gender`, `designation`, `department`, `@context`)
VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$gender', '$designation', '$department', '$e')";
```

In the My SQL I was able to put the `empid`, `empname`, `gender`, `designation`, `department`  data except the `@context`

please help me with this using @ mark in the php and mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the property name like so:

```
$e = $emp_data->profile->{'@context'};
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would work with arrays:

```
$emp_data = json_decode($json_obj, TRUE);
$e = $emp_data['profile']['@context'];
```